# Doing a css3 transition with on click jquery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this css which does a slide out transition

```
.slide_animation {
    transition: 10s;
    left: 0px !important;
    -webkit-transition-duration:800ms
}
```

and using jquery:

```
$(".shop_look").click(function(){
      $("#look").show();
      $("#look").addClass("slide_animation");
      $(this).fadeOut(2000);
   })
```

this works but there is no easing when the #look element shows, its too snappy, I want it to ease out like a smooth animation. thanks

Comment: Can you not just use `fadeIn()` instead of `show()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using that correctly, the display property has only two states, so you should probably use the opacity property instead (or both) :

```css
#look {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-duration:800ms;
}

#look.slide_animation {
     opacity:1;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/apKue/1/)

If you don't want transitions on everything, you can specify the property as well:

```css
transition-property: opacity;
```